# MySQL backup file includes HTML tags

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-backup

I'm trying to download the Drupal 7 database from production server. Unfortunately, It's showing HTML tags in last of the file.

```html
    <!-- PMA-SQL-ERROR -->
        <div class="error"><h1>Error</h1>
    <p><strong>SQL query:</strong>
    <a href="tbl_sql.php?sql_query=SHOW+TABLE+STATUS+FROM+%60i2819657_drup1%60+LIKE+%27login_destination%27&amp;show_query=1&amp;db=i2819657_drup1&amp;table=login_destination&amp;token=98a3c2701c0cfec8e0843f05dc044f9e"><span class="nowrap"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Edit" alt="Edit" class="icon ic_b_edit" /> Edit</span></a>    </p>
    <p>
    <span class="syntax"><span class="inner_sql"><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.6%2Fen%2Fshow.html&amp;token=98a3c2701c0cfec8e0843f05dc044f9e" target="mysql_doc"><span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">SHOW</span></a>  <span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">TABLE</span>  <span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">STATUS</span>  <span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">FROM</span>  <span class="syntax_quote syntax_quote_backtick">`i2819657_drup1`</span>  <a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.6%2Fen%2Fstring-comparison-functions.html%23operator_like&amp;token=98a3c2701c0cfec8e0843f05dc044f9e" target="mysql_doc"><span class="syntax_alpha syntax_alpha_reservedWord">LIKE</span></a>  <span class="syntax_quote syntax_quote_single">'login_destination'</span></span></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>MySQL said: </strong><a href="./url.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman%2F5.6%2Fen%2Ferror-messages-server.html&amp;token=98a3c2701c0cfec8e0843f05dc044f9e" target="mysql_doc"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
    </p>
    <code>
    #2006 - MySQL server has gone away
    </code><br />
    </div>
```

Can anyone please hep me on it?

Comment: Let's just make that code you posted into a code snippet, so it can be "run", and what do we see? `MySQL said: #2006 - MySQL server has gone away ` - something for you to go research now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself.

1. Create **php5.ini** file in root of your web hosting cPanel account.
2. Put this line in that file.

   **mysql.connect_timeout = 120**
3. Now logout your cPanel account and login again.
4. Go to PhpMyAdmin to export the backup file and download.
5. Once downloaded. Open this file in any text editor and page down to end to verify if there are not HTML tags. It means problem fixed.

Thanks